# My Binary search only returns that the number cant be, C

Tags: c, binary-search

Beginner here, I can't fix the error because I don't know what to do anymore or what is wrong with the code. Every input returns it shows "The number is not part of the array" no mater the number. I am using 100 radomized numbers, ranging from 0 - 900 as my list which have been sorted. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me on this.

```
void find(int * randomized, int size, int * menu) {
    if((*menu)>=2){

        printf("\nEnter the number you are searching for: ");

        char tal[SIZE];
        fgets(tal, LENGTH, stdin);
        strtok(tal, "\n");

        int choice=atoi(tal);
        int high=size-1;
        int mid;
        int low = 0;
        int remainder, split;

        while (low<=high){
            mid = (low+high)/2;
            if(randomized[mid]==choice){
                remainder=(mid+1) %10;
                split=(mid+1) /10;
                if(remainder == 0 && split == 10){
                    remainder=10;
                    split=10;
                }
                else if( remainder == 1 && split == 0){
                    remainder=1;
                    split=1;
                }
                else if(remainder == 0 && split >0 && split <10){
                    remainder=10;
                    split=10;
                }
                else{
                    split=(mid+1)%10;
                }
                printf("\n The numer %d is a part of the array.\nColumn: %d\n Line: %d", choice, remainder, split);
                return;
                
            }
            else if(randomized[mid] !=choice){
                printf("\nThe number %d is not part of the array.\n", choice);
                return;
            }
            else if (randomized[mid] <choice){
                low=mid+1;
            }
            else{
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        (*menu=4);
    }
```

Comment: Please prove a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example you can try to debug step bu step using gdb for example

Comment: use print statements to display the values of randomize[mid] and choice where it spits out "number is not part of array", as well as throughout your code to properly follow the logic

Comment: Just staring at the code is a difficult debugging technique even for experts.  You need an approach that helps you track what the code is doing as it runs to get an idea of what's going wrong.  Good old print-statement debugging is a simple, tried and true technique, and running your program under the control of a debugger is a more powerful one.

Comment: Since you are only using 100 random numbers from the range of 0 - 900 for your list of numbers to search over, you will choose an unfindable number 8 out of 9 times if you are picking randomly yourself.

Comment: Did you verify the list is sorted?

Comment: @jxh I am picking a number i know is in the list, and yes im verifying it's sorted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will give that a try.

Comment: Since it is an exercise, then, do it for the numbers from 1-10 to start.

Answer (score 1):

The code has an `if` followed by three `else` tests. Since the first test is for **equality**, and the second for **inequality**, then the last two `else` code blocks can never be entered.

```
if(randomized[mid]==choice){
    // some code ...
}
else if(randomized[mid] !=choice){
    // some code ...
}
else if (randomized[mid] <choice){
    // some code ...
}
else{
    // some code ...
}
```

The code has been made hard to follow because too much functionality has been crammed into the binary search. It should focus one job, and give a true or false result, which you then act on.

Comment: **Good catch!**

Comment: I guess you could mention one solution is to use `bsearch()` instead of implementing your own binary search.